# How to use CASE to select MAX(date) WHEN active=1? (without subquery)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to optimize some code, if this is possible it's not only more elegant but it would save me running several other queries to get the same data and speed up my while loop considerably.

How would I CASE select the MAX (date) where it is also `1` from a dataset like this?

```
0   2020-06-30
0   2020-06-26
1   2020-06-25 <---- I want this guy
0   2020-06-24
0   2020-06-24
0   2020-06-23
0   2020-06-22
0   2020-06-22
0   2020-06-16
0   2020-06-16
0   2020-06-12
1   2020-06-12
0   2020-06-11
0   2020-06-01
0   2020-06-01
```

I tried something like this but obviously this doens't work.

```
CASE 
WHEN aty.type_count = '1' AND ac.activity_date = MAX(ac.activity_date) 
THEN ac.activity_date 
ELSE 0 
END 
AS max_date_active
```

I can't just sort by both columns as sometimes there are no `1` results. I guess I could make the result set a query, but I am running other `SUM(CASE())`'s on the same data set, so I'm trying to make it all work together as a single, elegant query.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I updated the name to "without subquery" as once I'm using a subquery I might as well just create a separate query to get the results. I'm curently thinking I just get the entire data set back, and figure out what I want using a PHP loop. Not as elegant but at least it saves several complex joined queries.

Comment: FYI - I updated the name to "without subquery" as once I'm using a subquery I might as well just create a separate query to get the results. I'm curently thinking I just get the entire data set back, and figure out what I want using a PHP loop. Not as elegant but at least it saves several complex joined queries.

Comment: You should really make that sort of comment on the answers so that the users who posted them see it; otherwise you are unlikely to get updated answers.

Comment: Fair enough, done!

Comment: @Maurice using a correlated subquery is not particularly complex. I would compare the speed and memory consumption of doing this in mysql vs pulling the resultset into php and using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

A `LIMIT` query might be the easiest option here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE type_count = '1'
ORDER BY activity_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If there might be more than one record with a type count of 1, tied for the latest date, then we can use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    type_count = '1' AND
    activity_date = (SELECT MAX(activity_date) FROM yourTable WHERE type_count = '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it's not possible to do exactly what I wanted. Subqueries are possible but if I'm processing the query twice inside itself I'd rather handle them separately.

In the end I just kept the result set shown in my question, and then did a basic loop in PHP to extract the info I wanted.